# The differences between Java project in Eclipse and Eclipse itself?

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is my doubt:

One can find the "Compiler" in Eclipse by clicking on Window-->Preferences-->Compiler. If I create a new Java project in Eclipse, then I can find the "Java compiler" in the project properties.

In Eclipse, the JRE's version and compliance level, both are 1.7, but the project I have created uses a JRE and compliance level, both of version 1.6 (by external class folder). Does it cause any difference after I compile and see the result of project compilation? And will the project run in JRE 1.6 without affecting the Eclipse compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean by "eclipse itself" are actually your **workspace** preferences. By default, all your projects are using the settings that you define for that **workspace**. Then, if you want to, you can enable **project specific** settings for your different projects.

The important thing to understand: in both cases, it is the eclipse compiler that creates your .class files; according to the settings that you made. So, in that sense, it doesn't make a direct difference.

The key thing to understand: when you are enabling the 1.6 compliance setting, the class files that you create will also work when they are deployed to a system that runs Java 1.6.

In other words: the one and only reason for such a setup would be such a requirement: that your compiled classes will be executed by JVMs on a different level later on. If that is not the case, then there is no point in having different compliance settings!

Comment: Great. Any comments from the brave downvoter on why he just downvotes three answers?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing @GhostCat

Comment: Wow, it's useful , thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome.